# Compact set intersects finitely many elements of an open set covering of a bounded open set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

I'm reading Functional Analysis by Rudin and get a trouble in theorem 6.28, in page 169. It says at the beginning of the proof that

**There are compact cubes $Q_{i}$ and open sets $V_{i}(i=1,2,...)$ such that $Q_{i}\subset V_{i}\subset\Omega, \Omega$ is the union of $Q_{i}$, and no compact subset of $\Omega$ intersects infinitely many $V_{i}$.**

In the statement, $\Omega$ is open subset of $R^{n}$. I doubt this statement if I explicitly add an assumption that $\Omega$ is bounded and $V_{i}$ are distinct. I have trouble proving it and I can't make up a concrete example. In my examples, I always find a compact subset intersecting infinitely many $V_{i}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Q$ is a cube let $L(Q)$ denote the length of a side of $Q$. If $Q$ is a closed cube, let $2Q$ denote the closed cube with the same center such that $L(2Q)=2L(Q)$.

Given $\Omega$, choose a bunch of [dyadic cubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_cubes) one step at a time.

Start by including all the dyadic cubes $Q$ with $L(Q)=1$ and $2Q\subset\Omega$.

Now add all the dyadic cubes $Q$ such that $L(Q)=1/2$ and $2Q\subset\Omega$, *and* such that $Q$ is not contained in one of the cubes chosen previously.

Then add the dyadic cubes of side length $1/4$ with $2Q\subset\Omega$ and such that $Q$ is not a subset of any of the cubes chosen in the previous two steps.

Etc. Call all those cubes $(Q_j)$. Let $V_j$ be an *open* cube with the same center as $Q_j$ and $L(V_j)=3/2L(Q_j)$.

Comment: I'm not sure how could you make sure that the following level (smaller size) cubes are not contained in the proceeding level  (larger size) cubes when levels get more?

Comment: @Hua ??? This is immediate from the construction! By definition, if $Q$ is a cube added at the $n$-th stage then $Q$ is not contained in any cube that was added at any previous stage.

Comment: So you mean you will not add the cube into the current collection $(Q_{i})$ if it is already contained in one element of the collection? Does this mean at a certain stage the collection will not grow and this collection may contain only finite number of cubes? I thought the procedure will go on forever to let $L(Q)$ go to $0$.

Comment: @Hua Yes. No. Look at an example. Say $\Omega = (0,\infty)\subset\Bbb R$. At the first stage we add the cubes $[1,2]$,$[2,3]$, etc. At the second stage we add the cube $[1/2,1]$. At the third stage we add the cube $[1/4,1/2]$. Etc.

Comment: I guess I get your point, so your procedure is a bit different from the wiki, it requires cubes of each stage partition the whole space, while your procedure only require the all cubes from all stages cover the space. Right?

Comment: Thanks very much for this good example! But I prefer to wait for a longer time for a formal proof. If no other answers, I will accept yours. Thanks!

Comment: @Hua I have no idea what you're referring to when you say my proof is "different from the wiki".

Comment: The wiki says cubes of each scale partition (cover) the whole space, while in your procedure, cubes of each scale not necessarily partition (cover) the space. Instead, you only require the all cubes including all scales cover the space.

Comment: I understood the meaning of the sentence you wrote. I don't know what "wiki" you're referring to. If you want me to comment on how that proof differs from what I wrote you might just possibly consider providing a link to the proof so I could look at it.

Comment: Oh sorry for misleading, it actually refers to your link [Dyadic cubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_cubes)

Comment: @Hua You're not making any sense that I can see, sorry. You ask about my proof as compared to the proof at that page. There is no proof at that page of the result you're asking about!

Comment: Er, more precisely, in your second comment, you give a example which contains a collection of cubes, i.e, $\{[\frac{1}{2^{n}},\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}],[1,2],[2,3],[m,m+1]\}$. This whole collection cover the space $[0,\infty)$, but cubes of a certain scale does not. This is the point where is different from the definition from this [Dyadic cubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_cubes). The first sentence of the page gives a defintion of dyadic cubes. From my opinion your cubes are not exactly dyadic cubes defined in the page.

Comment: @Hua You're entitled to your opinion. When I say "dyadic cube" I mean exactly dyadic cube as defined on that page.

Comment: @Hua See, you're confusing things, thinking this is the same as that when it's not. Yes, the dyadic cubes of side length $2^{-n}$ cover all of $\Bbb R^d$. The phrase "dyadic cube" does not mean the same thing as "a dyadic cube that I selected as one of the $Q_j$ in my construction".

Comment: @Hua Here's a simpler example of exactly the error you're making. You ask me to prove something. In the course of the proof I say "Let $S$ be the set of all even integers between $0$ and $6$, or in other words $S=\{0,2,4,6\}$". You find a place on the internet where it says that $10$ is an even number. So you tell me that my even numbers are not the same as the even numbers defined on that page.

Comment: I guess I get you point. Sorry I couldn't tell the difference between the cube you gave and those in the page, when you use the same word.

Comment: @Hua I used the same word because when I say "dyadic cube" I mean exactly the same thing! There _is_ _no_ _difference_ between my dyadic cubes and the ones on that page. _Exactly_ as in that example: I'm using the same word "even number" because I mean exactly the same thing as the web site does by "even number". The elements of $S$ are not all the even numbers - I didn't say they were, and the fact that the elements of $S$ are not all the even numbers doesn't show I mean something different by "even number". You need to learn to read much more carefully and accurately.

Comment: @Hua When I say you need to learn to read more carefully - from your comments it seems like when I wrote "all the dyadic cubes $Q$ such that $L(Q)=1/2$ and $2Q⊂\Omega$, _and_ such that $Q$ is not contained in one of the cubes chosen previously" what you _read_ was just "all the dyadic cubes".

Comment: I get your point. Thanks